# How many elements does group of symmetries of this logo have?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry

I could only rotate but not reflect it. So is it $2$?

[image: Logo]

Comment: No it doesnt..updated the question :)

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z-like flash across the middle prevents any reflection symmetry, so your symmetry count is correct at 2.